# Code First Empty Navigation Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, code-first

I have a really weird issue going on that I can't seem to find the answer on google for.

I currently have the following Code First/DB structure:

```
public class Prospect {

    [Key]
    public int ProspectId { get; set; }
    public int ProspectCompanyId { get; set; }
    public int? ImportUserId { get; set; }
    public int? ProspectUserId { get; set; }
    public int? SalesUserId { get; set; }
    public int? CampaignId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CampaignId")]
    public virtual ICollection<CampaignEvent> CampaignEvents { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CampaignId")]
    public virtual Campaign Campaign { get; set; }
}

public class CampaignEvent
{
    [Key]
    public int CampaignEventId { get; set; }
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string ActionType { get; set; }
    public string ActionSubject { get; set; }
    public string ActionTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to return a query like:

```
var prospects = db.Prospects.Include("CampaignEvents");
```

The `prospects.First().CampaignEvents` is empty - when it should be populated with records.

I've even taken the SQL generated by the Entity Framework and executed it with it successfully returning the prospect and campagin events directly in the database.

I'm at a loss of what to do - its very odd, I receive no errors, just an empty collection.

Please let me know if you need any additional details!

Comment: Obvious question, but are you sure you have data?

Comment: Yes sir, 100% positive, I took the sql query that is generated by EF and ran it in my query analyzer and it returned data (including the campaign events) no problem. thats what is so weird

Comment: `null` or empty collection? Below Damith's answer you wrote `null`, in your question you write "empty collection". It's a big difference because an "included" collection must never be `null`, even without data in the DB.

Comment: It was null for his code below, its an empty collection for my code above. Notice his code below is simply pulling prospects that have CampaignEvents - the var value equaled null in that case.

Comment: Oh, I understand. But if Damith's query returns `null` it means EF thinks that there are no related `CampaignEvents` at all for any `Prospect`. Are you sure you query on the right database, not a different one that the query analyzer ran on? Did you check the connection string?

Comment: Can you run a simple test (in your app, not the analyzer): `bool hasEvents = db.CampaignEvents.Any();`. What is `hasEvents`?

Comment: Sure - I even took it one step further `var campaignId = db.Prospects.First().CampaignId.Value;

            var hasEvents = db.CampaignEvents.Any(p => p.CampaignId == campaignId);` - hasEvents is showing as true

Comment: Database is SQL Server with SqlClient provider, right? Do you have `GetHashCode` or `Equals` overridden in one of the classes? Does lazy loading work (can't really image if eager loading doesn't work)?

Comment: I have lazy loading disabled, the database is MySql using the latest MySql Connector - no overridden methods - I have other collections inside the Prospect class that work just fine - it appears its only this one that is acting up and I have no clue why

Comment: Hm, and the other collections are mapped the same way, i.e. no navigation reference in dependent class, just FK property and `[ForeignKey]` attribute on the collection?

Comment: No sir, nothing unusual, just FK attribute on the collection

Comment: Do you have a chance to rename `CampaignEvent.CampaignId` into `CampaignEvent.ProspectId` (wouldn't that be the more appropriate name anyway?) or `CampaignEvent.SomeOtherId` (including change of the ForeignKey attribute parameter on the collection of course), something that is different from the `Prospect.CampaignId` FK name, and test the query again?

Comment: Well, that wouldn't make sense because CampaignEvent are not associated with Prospects directly in that sense. The relationship would be a Zero or One to Many from the Prospect to the CampaignEvent - however, I will change the name just for testings sake to see if it fixes it

Comment: Why "not directly associated"? Your mapping defines a direct one-to-many (required, not zero) relationship between `Prospect` and `CampaignEvent`. (Non-nullable) foreign key of this relationship is `CampaignEvent.CampaignId` with a navigation collection `Prospect.CampaignEvents`.

Comment: Sure - because Prospects have campaign events associated to them based upon the campaign they are assigned to, and then campaign events are assigned to that campaign. If i were to have a direct relationship between Prospect and CampaignEvent it would require I have a unique campaignevent for every prospect (which isn't how the db is structured) - instead, the prospect is assigned to a campaign of which the campaign has campaignevents - sorry kind of hard to explain - hope you understand

Comment: Hm, but this sounds like business logic. Does it affect the database schema or mapping? According to your mapping you should have a "direct" foreign relationship between `Prospect` table and `CampaignEvent` table with a foreign key being `CampaignId` in `CampaignEvent` table.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
var prospects = db.Prospects.Include("CampaignEvents");

var value = prospects.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.CampaignEvents.Any());
```

Comment: I've tried this and it returned a null - its freakin weird man.. i cannot for the life of me figure out why Entity Framework is not loading this collection with the data its obviously pulling from the database.